# Cannot install Yii 1.x using Composer

Tags: php, yii

It seems that Yii is popular nowadays, and so does using composer (instead of installing your PHP libs manually), so I decide to give them a try.

Anyway, these are my steps:

1. mkdir "yii-dev" in /var/www/html (my box runs Debian 7 64)
2. mkdir -p yii-dev/protected/config
3. create a composer.json in /yii-dev/protected/config:

> ```
> { "repositories": [
>     {
>         "type":"composer",
>         "url": "http://packages.phundament.com"
>     }
> ],
> "require": {
>     "php": "5.6.5",
>     "yiisoft/yii": "1.1.6",
>     "yiiext/migrate-command": "0.7.2"
> },
> "config": {
>     "bin-dir": "bin/"
> },
> "autoload": {
>     "psr-0": {
>         "config": "./"
>     }
> },
> "scripts": {
>     "pre-install-cmd": "config\\ComposerCallback::preInstall",
>     "post-install-cmd": "config\\ComposerCallback::postInstall",
>     "pre-update-cmd": "config\\ComposerCallback::preUpdate",
>     "post-update-cmd": "config\\ComposerCallback::postUpdate",
>     "post-package-install": ["config\\ComposerCallback::postPackageInstall"],
>     "post-package-update": ["config\\ComposerCallback::postPackageUpdate"]
> } }
> ```

4. Then I add console.php in yii-dev/config:

> ```
> <?php
> return array(
>     'aliases' => array(
>         'vendor' => 'application.vendor',
>     ),
>     'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'..',
>     'name' => 'My Awesome Yii Site',
>     'components' => array(
>         'db' => array(
>             // PostgreSQL
>             'connectionString' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=yii_dev',
>             'emulatePrepare' => true,
>             'username' => 'yii',
>             'password' => 'yii123',
>             'charset' => 'utf8',
>         ),
>     ),
>     'params' => array(
>         'composer.callbacks' => array(
>             // args for Yii command runner
>             'yiisoft/yii-install' => array('yiic', 'webapp', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'),
>             'post-update' => array('yiic', 'migrate'),
>             'post-install' => array('yiic', 'migrate'),
>         ),
>     ),
> );
> ```

5. And finally, ComposerCallback.php in yii-dev/protected/config. The content is a bit long so I don't put it here. Instead, it can be found at http://www.shanedowling.com/yii-with-composer/

Then when I run "composer install", I get this:

> $ composer install
>
> Phundament 3 Installernn * download packages specified in composer.json
>
> - trigger composer callbacksnnStart Installation? [yes|no] yes
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'config\Yii' not found in
>   /var/www/html/yii-dev/protected/config/ComposerCallback.php on line
>   182
>
> Fatal error: Class 'config\Yii' not found in
>   /var/www/html/yii-dev/protected/config/ComposerCallback.php on line
>   182

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This might be quite old question. But still I had to face the same issue today to config composer to one of our existing old system which is using Yii1.1. This is what I did and it's working.

My project structure is:

```
project_dir/website/protected/  
project_dir/website/index.php
```

So, I installed the composer within /website/ directory.

> Install composer locally

```
$ cd website/
/website$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
/website$ php composer.phar -h
```

To update the system to require autoload.php, add following to the website/protected/config/main.php

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
```

Add following to .htaccess within website/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} vendor/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} composer.phar [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} composer.json [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} composer.lock
RewriteRule . index.php
```

All done. Just install what you want

```
composer require packegeName
```

Ref: https://devreadwrite.com/posts/add-the-composer-to-the-application-on-yii